# Register JavaScript alert at extreme end using RegisterStartupScript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

(*Note: Just to clarify the problem is not specifically related to C1WebDateEdit. It could be with any custom control which require JavaScript to render actual control*)
I have many C1WebDateEdit controls in my page. On a button click based on some condition I am displaying JavaScript alert message ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. These controls are inside UpdatePanel. The issue I am facing with it is, when these C1WebDateEdit has not value and page displays alert message, it displays "01/01/0001" behind the alert box and on closing alert it shows empty textboxes. 
The reason is, C1WebDateEdit creates actual control using JavaScript. and page renders alert message JavaScript before C1WebDateEdit controls' JavaScript.

For example: 
HTML markup
alert JavaScript
C1WebDateEdit JavaScript

Logical solution is get alert JavaScript after C1WebDateEdit JavaScript because it will allow C1WebDateEdit to load fully before alert box.

I found no inbuilt way in asp.net to change sequence, so I tries solution given [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Jan/02/Rendering-ASPNET-Script-References-into-the-Html-Header)  but It didn't work for me.

One possible solution I am thinking that I create Custom or WebUserControl and place at it last at the page in the UpdatePanel and PreRender event I call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to register alert message. Logically I think it will work 
 but trying to find that any one implemented any other solution for it?.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution is use "pageLoaded" event of PageRequestManager. I created below function for temporary fix:

```
function delayedAlertBox(strMsg)
{
    var fnc = function (a, b)
    {
        //remove reference so on next call it do not show previous alerts.
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_pageLoaded(fnc);
        alert(strMsg);
    }

    //add function reference to call on Ajax pageloaded event
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(fnc);
}
```

and calling in asp.net like simple function as given below:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "dd", "delayedAlertBox('Hi, how are you?')", True)
```

But still looking for any other good alternative. If I found other, I will post it.